# Blow up criterion in PDE theory

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I need a clear idea about how one can establish a blow up criterion on a solution of partial differential equation or ordinary one. I don't need lot of details. I just need a general idea supported by an example so everyone can understand it.

Comment: This is quite vague. Many ODEs and PDEs exhibit blow up. Just look at $x'(t) = x(t)^2$ with $x(0)=1$.